# Please, advice which BibTeX style to use

Tags: bibtex

I am looking for a BibTeX style which would format a reference to a journal article as follows:

> Feinberg E L *Sov. Phys. Usp.* **23** 629 (1980)

i.e.,

1. no punctuation,
2. no dots after initials,
3. title of a journal or a book in italic,
4. volume number in bold,
5. year on parentheses.

I see that there exist hundreds (if not thousands) of BibTeX styles but how one could find what is needed?

Comment: In situations such as yours, I believe the standard recommendation is *not* to hack an existing bibliography style but, instead, to run the `makebst` utility (part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package) to create a new bibliography style from scratch. The utility -- start it by typing "latex makebst" at a command prompt -- will ask you lots of questions and provide multiple-choice answers. Its output is a shiny new bst file with bullet-proof code that implements all of your bibliography formatting needs.

Comment: By the way, do I interpret your specs correctly as requiring that the titles of journal articles be omitted?

Comment: @Mico: yes, articla title is dropped.

Comment: Is this a standard style from some publication? If so, there may already be one doing this. The usual search strategy is based on who defines the style rather than the detail (which is otherwise quite hard to describe!).

Comment: I don't think that the makebst utility has an option to drop the article title entirely. Just select a reasonable-looking option when you get to the question about how the title should be formatted. It's not difficult to hand-edit the the bst file, find the function named `article`, and remove the instruction that inserts the (formatted) title field.

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes, I wrote a review for Russian journal. Unfortunately, they did not provide a custom bst file... They are Russians...

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov. have you asked?